# Section title slide with Pandoc and Beamer

Tags: pandoc, beamer

I am using pandoc + beamer for some slides. How can I create a title slide to introduce a new section?

For example

```
____Slide 1_____
Section 1 ...
* bla
* bla
* bla
________________


_____Slide 2____


    Section 2      <--- How do I create this guy?

________________


____Slide 3_____
Section 2 ...
* bla
* bla
* bla
________________
```

Comment: It doesn't look like pandoc-markdown. What does your actual slides look like? In general, if you use level-2 or level-3 headings for regular slides, you can create a section title with a level-1 title (or any level title superior to that of slides. cf. http://pandoc.org/README.html#structuring-the-slide-show

Comment: Alright, that works, must have been a bug in my slides when I tried this before. Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: The thing is to make sure the level 1 title is followed directly by level 2 titles, with no content between them. This is what I was missing when I tried it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using pandoc just add the option --slide-level=2

See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#structuring-the-slide-show for details.

Answer (score 1):

As an MWE: `pandoc -t beamer --slide-level 2 foo.md -o foo.pdf`

The slide structure would need to be:

```
# This is a section slide

## This is the first slide in this section
 - list item 1
 - list item 2

## This is the next slide in this section
 - list item 1
 ![Image](./image1.png "alt text"){width:70%}

# This is the next section

## First slide of this section
 - list item 1
 - list item 2
```